# Photoshop 3D menu disappeared?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I’ve installed and used Photoshop CC on my system a few times.

1. The first time I installed Photoshop CC it was inside VirtualBox. The 3D menu showed up inside Photoshop, but was disabled because although my machine had 6GB or RAM, VirtualBox currently only supports a maximum of 500MB of virtual memory. Because of this, the functions accessible from the 3D menu were not available (for those using a Mac you may run Photoshop CC inside a virtual machine using Parallels, which supports up to 1GB or RAM).
2. So then I installed Photoshop CC on Windows 7 without installing it inside VirtualBox. The 3D menu showed up (and I am very sure of it because I was learning about Photoshop and that was my first time using the 3D menu). It was available. Recently, I’ve run Photoshop CC only to discover that the 3D menu is no longer there. It's almost as though some automatic update was carried out that got rid of the 3D menu. I've only found one other post on the internet reporting the problem.
3. Some posts report that you need Photoshop Extended to use the 3D features, with Photoshop Extended being a more expensive version of Photoshop, but this seems to be true only for Photoshop versions up to PS CS6. In PS CC it seems that the two have been merged into one product [according to this MacWorld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/2037029/adobe-announces-photoshop-cc-and-merges-photoshop-extended-into-main-program-to-create-a-single-pho.html).

So I doubt that Adobe CC upgraded to the wrong version of PhotoShop. How come the 3D menu disappeared from my version of PS CC?

Comment: Hello. As an update, I uninstalled PhotoShop CC and reinstalled PhotoShop CC from scratch (now running version 14.1.12 x64). Now the 3D menu still does not show up. I've noticed however that I can go to Edit -> Menus... -> Menu For: Panel Menus, and there I can see the first entry is named 3D. However, despite this, I see no menu on the PS menubar. Can't understand why this is.

Comment: Perhaps a problem between Areo of D3D in W7 guest addition CD ?
Or be carreful when 3D hardware video is check/uncheck in Virtualbox vm video settings ? If it is resolved for U, I take info because for me I still have correlated problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is your case, but when you use some hacking to keep the try out version running after the 30 days period, if done incorrectly, Photoshop changes from Enhanced to standard. In previous versions this is clear at the start logo but in CC, the visible clue is the absence of the 3D menu.